# Solution to too many lines for textbox to handle (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, textbox

I'm creating a windows forms application with MS Visual Studio 2010. The problem is that I need to print over 1 million lines of text to a textbox on the GUI. I'm first using a StringBuilder to prepare the string then just printing it to the textbox. Since there are so many lines, the text fails to show on the textbox and I just get a blank box. I know the string has been built properly as I can print all the text to a file just fine.

I was wondering whether someone can suggest a way to handle this situation?

What can I do to display all this text on the GUI?

Comment: "I need to print over 1 million lines of text to a textbox on the GUI"  - That seems like a terrible idea. I think you should paginate / load only a small buffer at a time.

Comment: What do you expect your users to do with a million lines of text?

Comment: They fit on the screen as there are scroll bars. I can go up to about 400,000 lines before it starts to blank.

Comment: I think if we knew what the user is expected to do with all that text, we could help provide a better solution to the problem

Comment: Peregrine, I have that many lines because they're all records.

Comment: That means, by definition, they don't fit on the screen - it must be virtually enlarged, and a ridiculous amount, at that. Blindly doing this, as has been indicated, is a terrible idea. Please consider alternatives. For humans, this amount of data is an irrational amount to even consider at any one time.

Comment: Just print the first  60,000,  no one will notice

Comment: Grant, can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: With a million lines, you've go nearly 2MB just in CRLF. Add to that the size of each row & you'll need to hold all that in memory. From an interface point of view, a user can't really be expected to cope with a million lines of text. Summarising or paging would be much more useful & less likely to bring your app to it's knees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***That is a bad design idea!!*** In the user perspective way he will never be able to handle the 1 million lines of text. If not, take this example: If he takes 20 seconds per line he will need about 5555.55 hours to read them all, aprox. ***3.5 Years*** (considering 8 h/day on a 200 day year). Imaginge also a scrollbar for 1 million lines: in a 800 pixel height, 1 pixes scrollbar move will scroll 1.250 lines of text.
Now, the technical part, if you put 1.000.000 lines in a text box, if you consider that in average each line has 40 characters ( that's about 40.000.000 in ASCII and 80.000.000 in UTF-16), in rough terms and in the best case scenario about ***40 GB*** of memory just for the string.

***General idea: Don't do that!***

If you user requires to navigate in any of those million records, think about some grid interface with pagination and filtering.

Comment: reminds me of the time I had a bug where people were trying to make objects whos length would get you to the moon and back 13 and a half times. +1

Comment: "considering 8 h/day on a 200 day year"
... well I guess that makes sense